# I am getting the message "EXPORT: command not found" when ever i open terminal

Tags: 20.04

I am getting an "EXPORT: command not found" error whenever I open the terminal.

Comment: You've likely added an `export` command to an autorun script (the command is `export` which is not the same; case matters)

Comment: I used EXPORT instead if export in ~/.bashrc to export java. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I commented

> You've likely added an `export` command to an autorun script (the
> command is `export` which is not the same as "EXPORT"; case matters)

OP later confirmed it was in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: I've tagged question as "problem went away"... I don't think it'll be of use to future users